# Связать массив мелодий с массивом изображений

Tags: java, android, массивы, resources, imageview

Имеется вот такой метод.
Делал воспроизведение мелодий подряд по этому примеру:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383387/setting-an-array-of-songs-using-mediaplayer
Работает он так:
Мелодии из массива воспроиз. по порядку. Необходимо сопоставить мелодию и картинку. Т.е играет мелодия soundsRawResId[idx] (r.raw.1) должна запускаться анимация у элемента массива imageview  arr_imageB[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383387/setting-an-array-of-songs-using-mediaplayer).startAnimation(anim);

```
    public void playAllSongs() {


    idx = (idx + 1);
    if (idx >= 7) {
        idx = -1;

        playAllSongs();
    }
    else {

              AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundsRawResIds[idx]);
        arr_imageB[idx].startAnimation(anim);
        try {

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            afd.close();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


}
```

Массивы:

//музыка

```
private int
   [] soundsRawResIds = new int[]{R.raw.1, R.raw.2, R.raw.3,
            R.raw.4, R.raw.5, R.raw.6, R.raw.7};

//изображения, инициализация 
 for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }
```

Comment: Неясна проблема и есть сомнения, что представленный вами код таки реально проигрывает подряд музыку из массива

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мелодии подряд играют,все в норме.
проблема в шапке указана

Comment: Очень странно, что работает - по хорошему надо в слушателе окончания проигрывания новую песню играть, а не в цикле. А так неясно что вам мешает получить картинку из массива по индексу, коли их длины совпадают

Comment: Я всё ещё не понимаю в чём ваша проблема. Изменений в вопросе тоже не вижу. Вам не нужно много циклов. Достаточно одного. А ещё лучше вообще без них.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
 мне необходимо при воспроиз. мелодии soundsRawResIdsх[0]  начать воспроизводить анимацию arr_imageB[0].startAnimation(anim);
если делать так arr_imageB[i].startAnimation(anim);  то анимация применяется ко всем элементам

Comment: Опять не понятно где же анимацию-то запускаете? В цикле проигрывания музыки? Если да, то, получается, музыка магическим образом ставится в некую очередь...

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
обновил кода в шапке, добавил 
 for (int index = 0; index < soundsRawResIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index].startAnimation(anim);
}
сейчас у меня играет первая мелодия и анимация у всех imageview а должна у первого

Comment: Я написал ответ. И всё ещё не вижу никаких циклов с анимацией в вашем коде и не ижу в чём ваша проблема. И что вам не понятно из примера по ссылке мне тоже не понятно.

Comment: Ну так вы ж для всех кнопок анимацию же запускаете в цикле, а надо только для одной.... 0_о. Вы сами написали то, что вас удивляет же...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
так я пробовал,т.е я сам заранее знал,что у всех анмиация будет воспроиз. а необходимо только у определенного, вот и спрашиваю,что мне поменять

Comment: Вам надо убрать цикл и оставить запуск только одной анимации из массива. Индекс использовать тот же, что и для массива песен.

Answer (score 1):

**Все работает как часы!То что мне нужно!**

```
public void playAllSongs() {


            idx = (idx + 1);

            if (idx >= 7) {
                idx = -1;

                playAllSongs();
            }
            else {


                      AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundsRawResIds[idx]);
                if(idx-1<0){
                    //ничего не выполняется

                }
                else {
                    arr_imageB[idx-1].clearAnimation();
                }

                arr_imageB[idx].startAnimation(anim);

                try {


                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    afd.close();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }



        }
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
а возможно ли добавить в этот мето паузу и восрпоизвед. с момента паузы?
mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
у меня не прокатило,останавливает,но не воспроизводит

Answer (score 0):

1. Запустите одну песню из массива с индексом "счётчик".
2. Запустите одну анамацию из массива с индексом "счётчик".
3. Увеличьте счётчик на единицу.
4. Повесьте слушатель окончания проигрывания песни.
5. В нём повторите п1, п2 и п.3

Comment: все работает,только не могу понять как убрать такой баг, если перехожу к новой мелодии то анимация у предыдущего imagevie продолжает работать ,а нужно остановить.
  arr_imageB[idx].clearAnimation();
пробовал так останавливать в самом начале,но ничего не вышло

Может повесить setAnimationListener??

Comment: `arr_imageB[ index - 1 ].clearAnimation();` - как то так должно быть. Главное к "-1" элементу массива не обратитесь.

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
а вызывать в самом начале метода?

Comment: Вызвать много где и много как можно. Просто подумацте немного где вам конкретнее удобно. Можно и в начале. Но надо это соотнести с инкременированием индекса вашего.

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
 Главное к "-1" элементу массива не обратитесь.
в моем случае так и получается,что я обращаюсь к -1...
arr_imageB[ idx - 1 ].clearAnimation();

иниц. я     int idx = -1; в методе  idx = (idx + 1);
делаю так: arr_imageB[ idx - 1 ].clearAnimation();
и вижу ошибку,что вышел за пределы массива
      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=-1

Comment: @upward ну так проверьте же чему будет равен индекс минус один и если он меньше 0, то ничего не делайте...........................

Comment: Учитывайте эту ситуацию ифами. Если вы знаете, что код приведёт к ошибке - зачем его пишите? Если знаете, что будет ошибка в определённый момент - реагируйте на это...............

Comment: только учусь,не ищите логики)
спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Создайте `Map` of `Map` или `List` of `Map` для загруженного листа композиций. Для внешнего контейнера в качестве ключа используете имя файла (в случае `Map`) или индекс (в случае `List`). Для внутренних `Map<String,Object>` или `Map<String,String>` используете в качестве ключей строки `"name","image","music"` а в качестве значений - имя композиции, путь к картинке (или саму картинку, если `Object`) и путь к музыкальному файлу (или сам трек в случае `Object`).